# C++ - Calculating round off error in a sum series program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// on input n returns the value a_n as a double
double term(int n) { 
  double val = 1.0 / (n+1.0) / (n+1.0);
  if (n%2 != 0) val = -val;
  return val;
}


/* computes the sum for i from k to k+n-1 of term(i) by the
 * direct upwards method */ 
double direct_up(int k,int n) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    sum += term(k+i);
  }
  return sum;
}

int main() {
  cout.precision(16);
  int nterms = 0;
  int ft = 0;
  cout << "Enter first term, number of terms" << endl;
  cin >> ft >> nterms;
  cout << "The sum of the " << nterms << " terms starting at " << ft << endl;
  cout << "direct_up:     " << direct_up(ft, nterms) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I have created a program which takes a formula and adds term by term starting from the kth term to the (n-1)th term. However I am unable to work out  how to calculate the roundoff error after each term?

Would you be able help me with this please?

Comment: Do you mean truncation error?  That's the error resulting from only retaining n terms in an infinite series.

Comment: Sorry no, I meant roundoff error. I believe it has something to do with call by reference but I am not quite sure what

Comment: Call by reference?  No.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoundoffError.html

Comment: I know how roundoff error works, but I am unsure how I would be able to apply the theory into a functional piece of code that would tell me what the error is

Comment: You could run the code effectively to infinity (defined as the point when the sum no longer changes), and compare your result to pi * pi / 6.

Comment: Why would you compare it to pi* pi / 6, and how would I be able to do that?

Comment: That's what the series converges to.

Comment: I see! That makes sense, so in the context of my code, would pi*pi/6 be my "true value"?

Comment: What if I wanted to calculate roundoff error after each term?

Comment: Yup, pi * pi / 6 is the true value. Each term is much harder. By the way, you'll be closer to the correct answer if you run your loop backwards: always add smaller terms to a floating point total first.

Comment: I see, would you be able to offer any advice on how I can add an error estimation each term?

Comment: Would my absolute error be abs(present approximation - pi*pi/6))?